# Rest controller triggers AWS lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm new to aws and I wonder how to solve my problem.

My case is the following:
I have a rest controller, which returns an integer (this number represents time in miliseconds).

I would like to trigger aws lambda, when an integer is greater than some number.

I'm doing researach to find some solutions and I know that I may ask the controller for this value periodically (every 5 minutes or 1 hour), but I'm wondering if there is any way of solving it otherwise?

Thanks for your help!

PS. I don't want to schedule it periodically, but to use something like a listener for my rest. 
Ex. My rest controller returns value 3 and it's ok, but when my controller returns value bigger than, let's say, 10, I would like it to trigger lambda.

Comment: You want to schedule something? You're talking about "integers", when you mean "I want to trigger AWS Lambda, when a certain amount of time has passed". That's scheduling.

Comment: No, because as I understand it scheduling would cause the sitaution when I call controller periodically, and as I mentioned in my post, that is not what I need. I would like use something like a listener for my rest. Ex. My rest controller returns value 3 and it's ok, but when my controller returns value bigger than, let's say, 10, I would like it to trigger lambda.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you're really doing. What time are you fetching from a REST service?

Comment: The value that I return in my rest controller is the time of the lag in some external system in my project. It is given in miliseconds. It changes rapidly, because it is calculated during method call. So when I call this rest, the only thing I receive is some integer value. What I need to do is create some kind of alert, if this number is greater than some hardcoded value. When allert is triggered, then I need the lambda to run

Comment: @gariaable If the number is greater than some value put a message on to SNS topic and which can then in turn trigger a lambda function https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html

Comment: @gariaable Is your rest controller on an ec2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get the core problem right, but if your use case is just to have a schedule for when the lambda is being triggered, you don't really need to have an external service that will call it on an interval.

You can use CloudWatch, there in Events -> Rules it's possible to set up a custom schedule and set a lambda as target.

Found a guide showing how to do it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FynLOwBgJAU

Answer (score 0):

- Following are the different ways of invoking lambda synchronous and Asynchronous [aws bog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/understanding-the-different-ways-to-invoke-lambda-functions/) and [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-invocation.html)
- You can invoke a Lambda function over HTTPS by defining a custom RESTful API using Amazon API Gateway. This gives you an endpoint for your function which can respond to REST calls like GET, PUT and POST.
- You can schedule a lambda trigger on cloudwatch events [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) schedule expressions using rate or cron [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)
- [SNS to trigger a lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-sns-to-trigger-lambda-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in a semi-standard JAX-RS environment you can trigger this internally with a [ContainerResponseFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html).  A skeleton:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER) // or whatever makes sense
public class ResponseFilterImpl implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                       ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        // get response body with responseContext.getEntity().toString() or whatever works
        // if it contains what you want, trigger a Lambda
    }
}
```